# Postgres insert on conflict update using other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I having syntax error for the following sql which spent an hour but cant find any answer form postgres documentation.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (userid SMALLINT, point INT, timestamp TIMESTAMPTZ);
CREATE TABLE point (userid SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY, balance1 INT, balance2 INT);
CREATE TABLE settings (userid SMALLINT, bonus INT);
INSERT INTO settings VALUES (1, 10); -- sample data

WITH trans AS (
  INSERT INTO transaction (userid, point, timestamp) 
  VALUES ($1, $2, NOW()) 
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO point (userid, balance1) 
SELECT userid, point 
FROM trans -- first time
ON CONFLICT (userid) DO UPDATE 
  SET balance1=point.balance1 + excluded.balance1, 
      balance2=point.balance2 + excluded.balance1 + settings.bonus 
FROM settings -- tried USING, not work
WHERE settings.userid=excluded.userid;
```

My question is how can I include extra table without using FROM during update? My target is to keep all into 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear to me what you are trying to do. The way I understand it, is that you are trying to use the value from `settings.bonus` when updating the row in case `on conflict` kicks in.

This can be done using a co-related sub-query in the `UPDATE` part:

```
WITH trans (userid, point, timestamp) AS (
  INSERT INTO transaction (userid, point, timestamp) 
  VALUES (1, 1, NOW()) 
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO point (userid, balance1) 
SELECT trans.userid, trans.point 
FROM trans 
ON CONFLICT (userid) DO UPDATE 
  SET balance1 = point.balance1 + excluded.balance1, 
      balance2 = point.balance2 + excluded.balance1 + (select s.bonus 
                                                       from settings s 
                                                       where s.userid = excluded.userid)
```

Note however, that `balance2` will never be incremented this way because on the first insert it will be `null` subsequent updates will try to add something to `null` but any expression involving null yields null (`null + 5` is null).

So you either need to insert `0` when doing the insert the first time, or use `coalesce()` when doing the update, e.g.

```
balance2 = coalesce(point.balance2, 0) + excluded.balance1 + (select ...);
```

If it's possible that there is no row in `settings` for that user, then you need to apply `coalesce()` on the *result* of the sub-query as well:

```
... excluded.balance1 + coalesce( (select ... ), 0)
```

---

Also: you used `excluded.point` in your question which is incorrect. `excluded` refers to the target table `point` but that does not have a column point - you probably meant: excluded.balance1 (as that is the column into which the inserted `trans.point` will go)

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: `timestamp` is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's a keyword, but more importantly because it does not document what the column is for. Does it mean "created at"? "valid until"? "start at"? "obsolete from"? Something entirely different?</sup>